# Do date annotations on a B1/B2 visa restrict my duration of stay?

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas

I am a medical student. I am planning to go to the USA for my clinical electives, and applied for a visa on this basis. My visa got approved for 3 months and it expires on 30 March 2018. Under annotations, the duration of the electives program is specified, which is from 5 February 2018 to 3 March 2018.

I am planning to take an exam (USMLE Step 2 CS) while I am there, most probably on 20 March 2018. Does this annotation affect the length of my stay in the USA granted at the port of entry? Am I allowed to stay there after my electives end to sit the exam?

Answer (score 2):

You should normally get a six-month period of admission, but it's possible you'd be granted a shorter period.  To reduce the possibility of that happening, you can mention the exam when describing the purpose of your visit.  Having plans for return or onward travel shortly after the exam will also help.